# PHP comparing time values

Tags: php, string, time

I have tow strings formatted like the following:

```
$status = "15:00";
$time = "15:00";
```

I want to compare them using php simply:

```
if($status == $time)
{
echo 'true';
} 
else
{
echo 'false';
}
```

I get false for the previous values even they are the same(as strings).
I want to know if there is a way to change the type of them to "time" and compare them??

Comment: This code returns `true` for all php versions, [see](http://3v4l.org/IA5uk).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compare timestamps or [DateTime objects](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) instead of strings:

```
$status = new DateTime( '15:00' );
$time   = new DateTime( '15:00' );

echo $status == $time ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

**UPDATE**; based on the comment:

```
/* you can also check, which timestamps was earlier or later */
echo $status > $time ? '$status is later then $time' : '$time is later then $status';
```

Comment: This is the same as string compare as OP wrote. No need to initialize extra objects. But, if he will use other comparison operators, this is great solution.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, that is a bad example. But I like those DateTime objects as they give me great flexibility like setting timezones and so on.

Comment: I know, `DateTime` rockz ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtotime()` for time comparison. Check the manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$status = "15:01";
$time = "15:00";
if(strtotime($status) == strtotime($time))
{
echo 'true';
} 
else
{
echo 'false';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **strtotime()**, this convert the string date in a integer number, then is easily compare.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php